# MongoDB: Run Aggregate on multiple databases

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have many number of databases each containing data for each customer.

Is there any way to run an `Aggregate` which will hit multiple databases? I want to run `$group` on the complete dataset.

As a workaround, I'm putting the data from both of the `DBs` into a temporary collection  and then running the `$group` on top of this temp collection.

Is there any better way to this? I'm open to use any other technology as well!

Comment: MongoDB aggregate pipeline operates on a single collection in a single database.  You can join to another collection in the same database using $lookup.  If the data which is distributed across multiple collections then standard query and update functions will be difficult.  You might want to consider placing all the data into one collection, not just as a workaround, but as a permanent solution.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to have the aggregation pipeline operate on multiple databases simultaneously. MongoDB aggregation may perform a `$lookup` between collections to perform a join, but this is the extent to which it's possible to merge external data. Unfortunately manually merging data--either merging raw data into a single collection to perform a single aggregation or merging the results of multiple aggregations--is the only option available to you if you continue to use your existing architecture.

If you modify your database architecture to contain all customer data within the same database and restrict access based on e.g. a `customerId` field, then it would be possible to perform aggregation on all customer data simultaneously without any additional effort. As it stands, however, your existing architecture simply will not work for this.